# How to convert this code in Jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This code is using Javascript AJAX. How can I convert it into jQuery AJAX?

```
var mine  = new XMLHttpRequest();
mine.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (mine.readyState == 4 && mine.status == 200) {
        var abc = mine.responseText;
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(abc);
        document.getElementById("que").innerHTML = jsonResponse["que"];
        document.getElementById("op1").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op1"];
        document.getElementById("op2").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op2"];
        document.getElementById("op3").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op3"];
        document.getElementById("op4").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op4"];
        var cor = jsonResponse["cor"];
    }   
};
mine.open("POST","index.php",true);
mine.send();
```

Response:

```
{
    "que": "How much was the `Jade Hair Pin` worth in the episode `The Blind Banker`?",
    "op1": "9 Trillion",
    "op2": "9 Million",
    "op3":"9 Billion",
    "op4": "9 Zillion",
    "cor": "2"
}
```

Comment: All the information you need is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: @Kadaj friends don't let friends use W3Schools ;)

Comment: and which is better..JS Ajax or Jquery Ajax??

Comment: Even tho I linked W3 because it is very readable with nice example, why shouldn't I use w3 as example? I am genuinely curious, cause I don want to make mistakes if I don't have to xD

Comment: Jquery AJAX will handle browser compatibility troubles for you and is easier to use.

Comment: var cor = jsonResponse["cor"];  i want to use this value in other function..how to do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite Javascript to jQuery with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141148/rewrite-javascript-to-jquery-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (converted only AJAX call) :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(jsonResponse) {
        /* Should not be necessary */
        // jsonResponse = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
        document.getElementById("que").innerHTML = jsonResponse["que"];
        document.getElementById("op1").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op1"];
        document.getElementById("op2").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op2"];
        document.getElementById("op3").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op3"];
        document.getElementById("op4").innerHTML = jsonResponse["op4"];

        var cor = jsonResponse["cor"];
        dosomestuff(cor); // give "cor" to another function
    }
});
```

If it doesn't work, do the same parse thing on `jsonResponse`.

Comment: and which is better..JS Ajax or Jquery Ajax??

Comment: Jquery AJAX will handle browser compatibility troubles for you and is easier to use. Performance are quite the same

Comment: var cor = jsonResponse["cor"];  i want to use this value in other function..how to do that??

Comment: create the function somewhere : function dosomestuff(cor) and call it into the "success" jquery function : domestuff(jsonResponse["cor"]);

Comment: i want to compare value of 'cor' and value passed from this <button id="op1" onclick="check('1')"> ,i.e, '1' in this case in check() function...so how should i do that???

Answer (score 0):

This is fully converted to jQuery, even the selectors, setter, ...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "POST",
    // this line could be removed, because jQuery can make a auto-select too
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        // use jQuery to select elements and set html content
        $("#que").html(response.que).data("cor", response.cor);
        $("#op1").html(response.op1);
        $("#op2").html(response.op2);
        $("#op3").html(response.op3);
        $("#op4").html(response.op4);
    }
});

function check(value) {
    if( value == $("#que").data("cor") ) {
        // correct
    }
    else {
        // incorrect
    }
}
```

Comment: var cor = jsonResponse["cor"];  i want to use this value in other function..how to do that??

Comment: Well, you could declare the value outside of the success callback. But keep in mind, that AJAX is asyncronous, so the other function may not get the actually value to work with. Maybe better call the function directly in your callback and pass `cor` as parameter then. @DeepMuni

Comment: i want to compare value of 'cor' and value passed from this <button id="op1" onclick="check('1')"> ,i.e, '1' in this case in check() function...so how should i do that???

Comment: Ahh okay, that is the check when answering the question? What about storing the answer id in the question data with jQuery? `$("#que").data("cor", cor);` in your success and in your check function `if( value == $("#que").data("cor") )`. Thats pretty easy. I've updated my answer. @DeepMuni

Comment: thanks this also worked...n sorry bro last question....there are 4 button...if the button is pressed i want a new response to load in ajax...how to do that and also i want to keep a score of the correct ans..how to do that?

Comment: Just call an AJAX function again after your check function. Best would be to wrap the AJAX function and requse it every time. You can store the score somewhere in the page, or use `data` again. There are plety of ways. There is not a single answer for this. It depends on your page/code/usecase ... @DeepMuni